# Symfony2: Loop through nested entities in Twig

Tags: php, symfony

I need to iterate through nested entities in a Twig template.

Entity A -> OneToMany relationship with Entity B
Entity B -> OneToMany relationship with Entity C

Relationships are set up properly (at least from what I can tell) and in the controller I can iterate through the nested ORM results.

However, when I try the following in the Twig template, I receive an error that states that a method (property of Entity B) does not exist.

Here's the code I use in the Twig template:

```
    {% for entityB in entityA.collection %}
        {% for entityC in entityB.collection  %}
            {{ entityC.property }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The error that is thrown states that entityC.property does not exist.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

JB

Comment: Can you post the actual entities and the actual twig loops? Nested loops do work in twig, so there must be some other problem with your specific implementation.

Comment: Because of the sensitive nature of the project, I'd have to alter too many references in the code. However, I'll check into nested loops in Twig a bit more. Perhaps there is something wrong with the entity definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can. It must be an issue with your entities.
Check your spelling of the property on entityC.property and try printing entityC.id or another property that you know exists. The code you have is fine.

Comment: Twig couldn't find the property, because the setter/getter in the entity was named wrong. Instead of using 'public function getProperty()', it was 'public function getMyProperty()'. So, Twig couldn't find what it expected as entityC.property. Thanks for the hint!